# Running arcpy.AlterField_management 2,000 times takes too long?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, arcgis-pro, performance

I am trying to replace field names of a table stored in a file geodatabase using a dictionary as a lookup table. My field names got cut off from the Tabulate Area tool ([Tabulate Area Truncates Field Names in ArcGIS Pro?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/307313/tabulate-area-truncates-field-names-in-arcgis-pro)). The following process works, however since I have about 2,000 fields, the process is taking over an hour (and counting) to run, which defeats the purpose of making an automated tool in my case.

**Is there a way to run this process faster?**

I'm essentially looking to take two fields from the attribute table of my raster, turn them into a dictionary (key: value is CLASS_TRUN: Class_Name) and then replace the Tabulate Area tool output table's field names (each a unique value from CLASS_TRUN) with it's corresponding dictionary value (Class_Name).

I'm using python 3.4 for ArcGIS Pro.

```
classDict = {} 

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table = supervised_tiff, field_names = ['Class_Name', 'CLASS_TRUN']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        classDict[row[1]] = row[0] 

TabulateArea(in_zone_data = bad_label_shapefile, zone_field = 'crop', in_class_data = supervised_tiff, class_field = 'Class_Name', out_table = bad_sig_table)

output_table_fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(bad_sig_table)] 

for i in output_table_fields:
    if i in classDict.keys():
        arcpy.AlterField_management(in_table = bad_sig_table, field = i, new_field_name = classDict[i], field_type = '', field_length = 64)
```

Comment: Use MakeFeatureLayer, passing a FieldInfo instance to the field_info parameter; then save that to a new output feature class. This runs much faster (though I'm sure there are scenarios in which it wouldn't), but dealing with the obnoxious FieldInfo object typically isn't worth it.

Comment: changing 2000 field names takes you less than an hour manually?

Comment: @atxgis I'm trying to replace a workflow from ERDAS IMAGINE. Their version of tabulate area does not cut off field names and would take less than an hour.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses [FieldInfo](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/analyze/arcpy-classes/fieldinfo.htm) to create an in-memory layer/view with renamed fields and then export that to a new table. Note that this works both for feature classes and for tables. See the comments for explanation:

```
def rename_fields(table, field_name_dict, output_table):
    """
    Rename fields in a table.

    Parameters:

    table - The path/name of the table in which fields will be renamed

    field_name_dict - A dictionary mapping input field names to the desired
        output field names

    output_table - The path/name of the output table
    """
    # Get a list of all non-required fields in the input table
    fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(table) if not field.required]

    # Compile the FieldInfo object, based on the input field name dictionary
    f_info = arcpy.FieldInfo()
    for field in fields:
        f_info.addField(field, field_name_dict.get(field, field), 'VISIBLE', 'NONE')

    temp = 'Temp_View'

    # Since tables and feature classes require different ArcPy functions...
    #   Make a layer/view, using the FieldInfo
    #   Export the records to a new table/feature class
    if arcpy.Describe(table).datasetType == 'FeatureClass':
        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(table, temp, field_info=f_info)
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(temp, output_table)
    else:
        arcpy.MakeTableView_management(table, temp, field_info=f_info)
        arcpy.CopyRows_management(temp, output_table)

    return
```

Here's a generic example of calling the function:

```
my_table = r'C:\The\Path\To\My\TableOrFeatureClass'
fields_dict = {'Field1':'NewFieldName',
                'Field2':'AnotherNewFieldName'}
new_table = r'C:\The\Path\To\New\TableOrFeatureClass'
rename_fields(my_table, fields_dict, new_table)
```

And, here's how your code, above, would be altered to call this function:

```
classDict = {}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(supervised_tiff, ['Class_Name', 'CLASS_TRUN']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        classDict[row[1]] = row[0]

TabulateArea(in_zone_data=bad_label_shapefile, zone_field='crop', in_class_data=supervised_tiff, class_field='Class_Name', out_table=bad_sig_table)

new_table = r'C:\The\Path\To\New\TableOrFeatureClass'
rename_fields(bad_sig_table, classDict, new_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the 'in_memory' workspace in arcpy. This workspace does not write any data to the physical memory and only uses virtual memory space, increasing speed. I have used it in the past to speed up some geoprocessing code.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm

For this to work you will have to assign your feature classes/tables to this workspace and reference it like so:

```
#transfer data to in_memory
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(supervised_tiff, 'in_memory/supervised_tiff')
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(bad_sig_table, 'in_memory/bad_sig_table')

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(in_table = 'in_memory/supervised_tiff', field_names = ['Class_Name', 'CLASS_TRUN']) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    classDict[row[1]] = row[0] 
output_table_fields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields('in_memory/bad_sig_table')] 

for i in output_table_fields:
    if i in classDict.keys():
        arcpy.AlterField_management(in_table = 'in_memory/bad_sig_table', field = i, new_field_name = classDict[i], field_type = '', field_length = 64)
```

then transfer the output to your physical workspace

```
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion('in_memory/bad_sig_table', 'output_tbl')
```

If you use in_memory let us know how well it worked